# byobu won't let me create a new bash window when using xterm

Tags: linux, bash, byobu

I am using `byobu` within `xterm`. Whenever I try to create a new window with `bash`, the window opens then immediately closes. Whenever I create a window with plain old `sh` however, it works fine.

I am running [Crunchbang Linux](http://crunchbanglinux.org).

Comment: I apologize for the dupe. When I posted the first time it gave me a `408 Request Timeout` error so I tried posting again. Sorry.

Comment: Is there an `exit` or `return` in your `~/.bashrc` or similar startup file? Also, please detail the steps you are taking to produce this result.

Comment: In my .bashrc, at line 8 there is something that says `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`. And, to get this to happen, byobu has to be set to start at login, then I press F2 to create a new window with bash, after doing that, the window opens for a moment and then closes.

Comment: What is sh a link to?  /bin/dash?  /bin/bash?

Comment: What happens if you open a `sh`, then `exec bash` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but after closing the status window (Opened by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>), it works again.